# Responsive CSS query not working for iOS iPad Air 2

Tags: css, responsive-design

It's my understanding that this query would target specifically my iPad Air 2 and apply the styles that I have added.  However, nothing is applied and it looks the same as the Desktop view.  I had to apply a different menu for my website to scroll properly on my iPhone, (overflow-y:scroll / hidden didn't work so I created multiple sections that display menu options as opposed to displaying the content in a div) but I'm having troubles targeting iPads as they also do not scroll properly.

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1536px) and (max-device-width: 2048px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

/***
  my css goes here
 **/

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works on iPad Air 2

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this meta tag in before the query:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more about what it does here: [Responsive Meta Tags](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

You may want to not put all of the desktop and mobile css all in the same page but make links to different sheets.  That way you save on initial load time and won't waste time loading both of them. Like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (min-width: 821px)' href='css/big.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (max-width: 820px)' href='css/little.css' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I have the meta tag in my main index.  I currently use a main.css page for all of my main css and a responsive.css page for all of my media query css.  Although he responsive CSS is getting rather big as I have queries for iPhones, iPads, and widescreen devices > <